# DownloadOperation receive zero bytes sometimes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1-universal, background-transfer

I built a Windows 8.1 Universal application and I have to download some files. I use the `DownloadOperation` to do this task. The problem is sometimes in  Windows Phone 8.1, the Download receive only zero bytes. And the same application on Windows 8.1, always download the files normally.

Bellow is my code:

```
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();

file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(URL), file);

var progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressCallback);
await download.StartAsync().AsTask(progress);
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Have you checked the [Background transfer sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer). It works in my side. Besides, UWP apps can't work in Windows Phone 8.1. Are you sure you are building a Windows 10 UWP app?

Comment: i built an UWP for Windows 8.1. Maybe that's the reason

Comment: For Windows 8.1, you can try with [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61). Besides, please note that [tag:uwp] refers to Universal Windows Platform which is a common platform for all devices running Windows 10. For Windows 8.1 Universal app please use [tag:windows-8.1-universal] tag.